Migration guide from Classic QDK to Modern QDK for Q#
Is there any sort of migration guide from the classic QDK to the modern QDK. When I am trying to use functions, I keep running into this

This documentation refers to the Classic QDK, which has been replaced by the Modern QDK.
Please see https://aka.ms/qdk.api for the API documentation for the Modern QDK.

However, the link just goes to the repository. It has been frustrating to try and figure out some of the new syntax changes e.g.
using (...) to use
and also how many of the functions simply do not exist or take in completely different arguments now.

Oops. That link shouldn't redirect to the repo. That's not very helpful. I'll get that fixed.
The API docs on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp-lang/ are accurate for the Modern QDK.
In the latest release we also integrated docs into the VS Code extension. From the command palette, type "Q# API" and it should filter to the "Q#: Show API documentation" command, which will bring up all the APIs available in a window along with their docs. It still needs a little work to be really nice, but you should be able to Ctrl-F (Cmd-F on Mac) to search in the window.
The docs should also be up to date with language syntax changes. For a very high level overview, see https://github.com/microsoft/qsharp/wiki/Differences-from-the-previous-QDK . If you spot anything we missed let us know and we'll update it. Thanks!
